# Elasticsearch: bulk update multiple documents saved in a Java String?

Tags: elasticsearch

I can create the following string saved in a Java String object called updates.

```
{ "update":{ "_index":"myindex", "_type":"order", "_id":"1"} }
{ "doc":{"field1" : "aaa", "field2" : "value2" }}
{ "update":{ "_index":"myindex", "_type":"order", "_id":"2"} }
{ "doc":{"field1" : "bbb", "field2" : "value2" }}
{ "update":{ "_index":"myindex", "_type":"order", "_id":"3"} }
{ "doc":{"field1" : "ccc", "field2" : "value2" }}
```

Now I want to do bullk update within a Java program:

```
Client client = getClient(); //TransportClient

BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
//?? how to attach updates variable to bulkRequest?

BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
```

I am unable to find a way to attach the above updates variable to bulkRequest before execute.

I notice that I am able to add UpdateRequest object to bulkRequest, but it seems to add only one document one time. As indicated above, I have multiple to-be-updated document in one string.

Can someone enlighten me on this? I have a gut feel that I may do things wrong way.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: instead of parsing, creating the string and trying to attach this string as a bulk.. you can attach to bulkRequest while parsing itself.. ?? i dont think there is something which you are looking for.. even if there is.. it does the same thing internally.. dont you think?

Comment: karthik. Thanks for chiming in!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work fine for you.
For each document updation , you need to create a separate update request as below and keep on adding it to the bulk requests.
Once the bulk requests is ready , execute a get on it.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("field1" , "value1");
obj.put("field2" , "value2");
UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(index, indexType, id1).doc(obj.toString());
BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
bulkRequest.add(updateRequest);


obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("fieldX" , "value1");
obj.put("fieldY" , "value2");
updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(index, indexType, id2).doc(obj.toString());
bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
bulkRequest.add(updateRequest);


bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: Vineeth, by "new UpdateRequest(index, indexType, id)", which document are trying to update? I am hoping to add multiple document string in one statement. Not sure Elasticsearch allows me to do so.

Comment: This works, because this is what I am already doing. It appears that my initial attempt is not supported in Elasticsearch.

Comment: How can we add filterquery to update specific documents ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem where only 1 document get updated in my program. Then I found the following way which worked perfectly fine. This uses spring java client. I have also listed the the dependencies I used in the code.

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateRequest;

import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder;

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.UpdateQuery;

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.UpdateQueryBuilder;

private UpdateQuery updateExistingDocument(String Id) {
    // Add updatedDateTime, CreatedDateTime, CreateBy, UpdatedBy field in existing documents in Elastic Search Engine
    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest().doc("UpdatedDateTime", new Date(), "CreatedDateTime", new Date(), "CreatedBy", "admin", "UpdatedBy", "admin");

    // Create updateQuery
    UpdateQuery updateQuery = new UpdateQueryBuilder().withId(Id).withClass(ElasticSearchDocument.class).build();
    updateQuery.setUpdateRequest(updateRequest);

    // Execute update
     elasticsearchTemplate.update(updateQuery);
}
```